# How to import blender object with shaders into javascript project?

Tags: shaders, glsl

Have really cool-looking soap bubble in Blender, would like to use it in javascript project, but when I import it to javascript it's just gray ball.

Is it possible to export glsl code that would be extracted from shader nodes or any other way?

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Answer (score 0):

It's worth looking into [<model-viewer>](https://modelviewer.dev/) that supports GLFT. You would need to [look into how shaders work with GLTF and exporting from Blender](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/addons/io_scene_gltf2.html#exported-materials) and make another shader though. Basically, you can use Principled BSDF shaders in your material and HDRI maps with GLTF and it should export materials and then just use the HTML tag to display the GLTF file on your page as a 3d model.